# I want to shift "options" and "data" class to the left and right side of the page respectively

Tags: html, css

Also, Is there any better way to manage option links? I have used table to manage them. Later, I want to add padding and fonts to those links too. Or, should I use four anchor tags inside a div to manage them. I have tried several ways to achieve this. All of them failed, instead cluttered the code more and more. Please excuse the low-quality of the question, as this is my first time asking here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <img src="ignou.png">
        <h1>INDIRA GANDHI NATIONAL OPEN UNIVERSITY</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="options">
        <table>
            <tr> <td><a href="Home.html" class="active">Home</a> </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td><a href="ProgrammeList.html">Programme List</a> </td> </tr> 
            <tr> <td><a href="Registration.html">Registration</a> </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td><a href="ImportantDates.html">Important Dates</a> </td> </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="data">
        <h2>Welcome to IGNOU Homepage</h2>
        <h3>Aims and Objectives</h3>
        <p>.....</p>

        <h3>Strengths of IGNOU.</h3>
        <p>.... </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

body {
    margin: 1%;
}

.header img {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  float: left;
  
}

h1 {
  color: blue;
  text-align:center;
}

table{
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
} 

.data {
  float: right;
}
```

[This is how it looks as of now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Frsy.jpg)

[This is how I want it to look (only the position of text, ignore the rest)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XCV2.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap them in a `div` and then use `display:grid;` on the div and do `grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);` and for spacing `grid-gap: 16px`; Then you can use `grid-column: span 3` to the nav and `grid-column: span 9` on the main element